# How to debug and test MapReduce on local Window machine?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have found that debugging and testing a MapReduce project challenging.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import writables.Friend;
import writables.FriendArray;
import writables.FriendPair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FacebookFriendsMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, FriendPair, FriendArray> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FacebookFriendsMapper.class);

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "\t");
        String person = st.nextToken();
        String friends = st.nextToken();

        Friend f1 = populateFriend(person);
        List<Friend> friendList = populateFriendList(friends);
        Friend[] friendArray = Arrays.copyOf(friendList.toArray(), friendList.toArray().length, Friend[].class);
        FriendArray farray = new FriendArray(Friend.class, friendArray);

        for(Friend f2 : friendList) {
            FriendPair fpair = new FriendPair(f1, f2);
            context.write(fpair, farray);
            log.info(fpair+"......"+ farray);
        }


    }

    private Friend populateFriend(String friendJson) {


        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Friend friend = null;
        try {

            Object obj = (Object)parser.parse(friendJson);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            Long lid = (long)jsonObject.get("id");
            IntWritable id = new IntWritable(lid.intValue());
            Text name = new Text((String)jsonObject.get("name"));
            Text hometown = new Text((String)jsonObject.get("hometown"));
            friend = new Friend(id, name, hometown);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return friend;
    }

    private List<Friend> populateFriendList(String friendsJson) {

        List<Friend> friendList = new ArrayList<Friend>();

        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = (Object)parser.parse(friendsJson.toString());
            JSONArray jsonarray = (JSONArray) obj;

            for(Object jobj : jsonarray) {
                JSONObject entry = (JSONObject)jobj;
                Long lid = (long)entry.get("id");
                IntWritable id = new IntWritable(lid.intValue());
                Text name = new Text((String)entry.get("name"));
                Text hometown = new Text((String)entry.get("hometown"));
                Friend friend = new Friend(id, name, hometown);
                friendList.add(friend);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return friendList;
    }

}
```

For debugging and testing, I usually get the script above and put it inside a `public static void main(String[] args)` in another testing class and run in debug mode of Intellij IDEA with reading a sample data from the local filesystem. Hence, I am pretty sure that the mapper's logic is correct.
About the reducer script, I am not sure in details that how the mapper pass its outputs to reducer. I checked the sample Reducer scripts during my research and came up with the initial version of my reducers as below:

```
public class FacebookFriendsReducer extends 
    Reducer<FriendPair, FriendArray, FriendPair, FriendArray> {
    
    @Override
    public void reduce(FriendPair key, Iterable<FriendArray> values, Context context)
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        }
}
```

This is where I can not proceed further as I can not simulate how the mapper pass its output to the `FacebookFriendsReducer` and the `reduce` method. My current approach for debugging is to write the reducer logic in a `public static void main(String[] args)` and then running it in debug mode in the process before putting to its reducer class.

Can someone help me how to pass the correct output of the mapper into the reducer so that I can further work on the logic ?
If you have a better alternative for debugging and testing MapReduce on a Local window machine before packaging it into a jar file and shipping it to Hadoop cluster, please let me know.

**Edit for @OneCricketeer's answer:**

You can check the Driver (main class) as below:

```
public class FacebookFriendsDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String inputPath = "E:\\sampleInputPath\\inputFile";
        String outputPath = "E:\\sampleOutputPath\\outputFile";

//        if (args.length != 2) {
//            System.err.println("Usage: fberature <input path> <output path>");
//            System.exit(-1);
//        }

        //Job Setup
        Job fb = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "facebook-friends");

        fb.setJarByClass(FacebookFriendsDriver.class);


        //File Input and Output format
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(fb, new Path(inputPath));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(fb, new Path(outputPath));

        fb.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        fb.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

        //Mapper-Reducer-Combiner specifications
        fb.setMapperClass(FacebookFriendsMapper.class);
        fb.setReducerClass(FacebookFriendsReducer.class);

        fb.setMapOutputKeyClass(FriendPair.class);
        fb.setMapOutputValueClass(FriendArray.class);

        //Output key and value
        fb.setOutputKeyClass(FriendPair.class);
        fb.setOutputValueClass(FriendArray.class);

        //Submit job
        return fb.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new FacebookFriendsDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

}
```

The sample Driver class above which I created based on other MapReduce job existing in our system. But I can not make it work on my Local Window Machine with the error below:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59143', transport: 'socket'
23/01/10 10:52:22 ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.preProcessForWindows(GenericOptionsParser.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at FacebookFriendsDriver.main(FacebookFriendsDriver.java:60)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/Users/Holyken/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.3.0-cdh5.1.0/hadoop-auth-2.3.0-cdh5.1.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
23/01/10 10:52:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/01/10 10:52:23 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
23/01/10 10:52:23 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1090)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:633)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:976)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:976)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:612)
    at FacebookFriendsDriver.run(FacebookFriendsDriver.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at FacebookFriendsDriver.main(FacebookFriendsDriver.java:60)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59143', transport: 'socket'
```

Can you elaborate more about how I can run MapReduce job on my local filesystem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set breakpoints in code from an IDE. You don't even need a real hadoop cluster. The code will run the same in local filesystem.

Otherwise, you can write unit tests, as well. For instance, your json parsing function, looks like it can return null values on exception, then you continue adding null values into your mapper output... You also don't need to convert a list to an array just to create a json array

Your main method for mapreduce for a Job driver application is what you'd start in a debugger.

> can not simulate how the mapper pass its output to the FacebookFriendsReducer

The parameters are given like a `GROUP BY key` operation. Your value is an iterable of arrays, so you need to loop over them.

Not clear what your reducer needs to output, so the output types might not be correct

Comment: it would be best if I can run and debug the MapReduce job on my local filesystem. I have edited my question above. Can you check and elaborate more on how this can be done ?

Comment: I run this code all locally, and I vaugely recall that I can set breakpoints - https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox#mapreduce-sandbox ; I'm sure you can search how to use Junit with mapreduce code, as well.

Comment: But 1) You need `winutils` installed on Windows for running any Hadoop code 2) You need to pass arguments to the main class, and/or hard-code your FileInputFormat paths

Comment: @KenMasters [Hadoop source code has unit tests](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/TestAggregateWordCount.java)